# Click num botão através da Class

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton">Submit</button>
```

E gostaria de fazer um *click* nele através de um evento em javascript, só que está que a dar-me o seguinte erro :
**Uncaught TypeError: l.click is not a function(…)**

Código que utilizo:

```
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton');
l.click();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o seletor `getElementsByClassName`, o resultado será um array com todos os elementos que contenham essa classe, então para corrigir o erro, você só precisa definir um índice, por exemplo `l[0]`, porém, se você irá atribuir o evento a apenas um item, o ideal é usar o atributo `id` e recuperar o elemento com a função `getElementById`.

Mas tem outro erro no seu código, para atribuir um evento ao elemento, você precisa usar a função `addEventListener`, da maneira como você fez, com o `click()`,  irá apenas simular o evento no elemento. Veja abaixo um exemplo funcional.

```js
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block betButton');
l[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('teste');
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block betButton">Submit</button>
```